# Process javascript object from html lists

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a html structure as,

```
<ul>
    <li>data</li>
    <li><strong>data</strong></li>
    <li><span><a href="data.link">data.name</a></span></li>
</ul>
```

I want to process it to javascript object something as below,

```
[
    {
        'index': 0,
        'render': function (data) {
            return data;
        }
    },
    {
        'index': 1,
        'render': function (data) {
            return '<strong>' + data + '</strong>';
        }
    },
    {
        'index': 2,
        'render': function (data) {
            return '<a href="' + data.link + '">' + data.name + '</a>';
        }
    }
]
```

I tried this code but the data parameter which is a json object are not being resolved in render field content.

```
var obj = [];

        $('ul li').each(function(i, content){
            var row = {};
            row.index = i;
            row.render = function(data) {
                return content;
            };

            obj.push(row);
        });
```

What I am looking is this code should work,

```
var data = {};
data.name = 'Example';
data.link = 'http://example.com';

console.log(obj[2].render(data));
```

It must return `<a href="http://example.com">Example</a>` as string.

Comment: you will have to parse the html attributes

Comment: if you can modify your html template, to be an actual template, you would be better off.

Comment: What exactly are you wanting? I set up a JSFiddle and the render method *is* returning the contents of each particular list item. http://jsfiddle.net/heksh7Lr/

Comment: @bloodyKnuckles, here I've updated the fiddle code http://jsfiddle.net/heksh7Lr/1/

Comment: I'm not sure. Something like this perhaps? http://jsfiddle.net/rxz5st8u/

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for a string concatenation?

**https://jsfiddle.net/oeavo45w/**

```
var obj = [];
$('ul li').each(function (i, content) {
    var row = {};
    row.index = i;
    row.render = function (data) {
        console.log(111, data)
        return '<a href="' + data.link + '">' + data.name + '</a>'
    };
    obj.push(row);
});

var data = {};
data.name = 'Example';
data.link = 'http://example.com';

console.log(obj[2].render(data));
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:** Parse an HTML Object and Evaluate Text as `data` Variable

Grab `content` and split it on the variable name `data`, making sure to accommodate key names. Provide the resulting array to a `render` function that checks for key names and replaces the placeholders with data supplied in the `render` parameter.

```
var obj = [];

$('ul li').each(function(i, content){
    var content_arr = content.innerHTML.split(/data\.?([^"<]+)?/);
    var row = {};
    row.index = i;
    row.render = function(data) {
        var return_string = '';
        for ( ii in content_arr ) {
            if ( ii % 2 ) {
                if ( content_arr[ii] ) {
                  return_string += data[content_arr[ii]];
                }
                else if ( 'string' === typeof data ) {
                    return_string += data;
                }
            }
            else { return_string += content_arr[ii]; }
        }
        return return_string;
    };
    obj.push(row);
});

// data object
var data = {};
data.name = 'EXAMPLE';
data.link = 'http://example.com';
// <span><a href="http://example.com">EXAMPLE</a></span>

// or data string
data = 'testme';
console.log(obj[1].render(data));
// <strong>testme</strong>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/heksh7Lr/6/

(Ya, I'm guessing HTML template libraries will be more powerful.)